Remove contents of cell in Word table, shift components behind it to fill empty cell?
I am searching for a similar solution to the one posted here in which I have a word document with a succession of cells (images with captions in the cells) arranged in an order. The solution on that post is the scenario to shift each cells components down and to the right if you want to add a new item and works perfectly!!
What I want to be able to do, is remove an item midway through, and shift everything behind it to the left / up to the new empty cell.
Using a similar example to the previous poster:
Aberdeen -tab- Ashford -tab- Bath -tab- Bedford -tab- Birmingham -tab- Bolton
Bradford -tab- Carlisle -tab- Cheltenham -tab- Chester -tab- Corby -tab- Derby
If I wanted to remove Bolton, I want to shift Bradford up next to Birmingham (instead of leaving an empty cell) and then shift each one up one cell position.
Is this possible?

To answer your question, yes it's possible, instead of moving text to the next cell, you move it to the previous one. Can you show us how you have tried to modify the code you link to in order to accomplish your goal?
